# Will_paginate stuck on page 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

For some reasons, my `will_paginate` collection is stuck on page 2. I have the usual links the view helper provides except every page after page one links to:

```
http://localhost:3000/ceo/gr_messages?page=2
```

I have tried to add the `:order` option with no luck. I have also ensured that the request is a get as mentioned [here](http://wiki.github.com/mislav/will_paginate/simple-search)

```
def gr_messages
    @organisation.gold_care!
    @messages = @organisation.messages.paginate(:per_page => 10, :page => params[:page], :order => 'id')

    if request.xhr?
        render :partial => 'messages_and_pagination'
    end
end
```

Comment: It sounds like you are somehow manually setting the page in your controller so that it always generates the next page link as if the current page was the first one. Can you include your view/controller code?

Comment: It might be helpful for us if you can post the controller action code that do the search.

Comment: Oops sorry! The code is included above. Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a known bug in older will_paginate versions. Please update the gem:

```
gem update will_paginate
```

Comment: Hi Mislav, I was using version 2.3.7, which is not so old. I upgraded to 2.3.12 and the problem is still there. I am using the plugin if that makes any difference. Any ideas about where I should be looking to fix this?
Thanks

Comment: Scratch that. I switched from the plugin to the gem and now its fine.
Thanks!

Comment: Plugin (if you fetch code from git) and gem are the same code. They will work exactly the same way if you install them correctly. I recommend gem usage to most users because gems are easy to install and update.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to resurrect the dead here, but I wanted to add that I just shared and resolved a similar experience.

For me, will_paginate was running fine for months (Rails 2.3.8 and will_paginate 2.3.15), and then all of a sudden, I began having the same problem as you on 2/3 servers (without making ANY changes to packages on the server or code).

I fixed the problem by uninstalling will_paginate, restarting the rails server, re-installing will_paginate, and restarting one more time. Restarting rails in the middle and having it come up in a faulted state was necessary for this to work.